# Compute ratios $\frac{XP}{PY}$ and $\frac{BQ}{QC}$ in terms of lengths r=$\overline{AX}$, s=$\overline{XB}$, t=$\overline{AY}$ and u=$\overline{YC}$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, proof-explanation

Show that the only way these ratios can be equal is if both ratios equal one, and show that in that case, $\overline{XY}$ is parallel to $\overline{BC}$.

I have $\overline{AB}$$\overline{XP}$$\overline{CY}$=$\overline{BX}$$\overline{PY}$$\overline{AC}$ but I'm not sure what to do with it.

[image: Triangle Diagram]

Comment: I should have mentioned that for my purposes the question is supposed to be solved using Cevians in $\Delta ABC$ and exterior ones in $\Delta AXY$. Menelaus Theorem is the next section -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the intersection of $PQ$ and $XC$ be $O$. By Menelaus theorem,

$${PX\over XY}\cdot {u\over t+u}\cdot {AO\over PO}=1$$

$${PY\over XY}\cdot {s\over r+s}\cdot {AO\over PO}=1 $$

Divide the two equations,

$${PX\over PY}={s(t+u)\over u(r+s)}$$

By Ceva theorem,

$${BQ\over QC}\cdot {u\over t}\cdot {r\over s}=1$$

Hence

$${BQ\over QC}={st\over ur}$$

If they are equal, $${st+su\over ur+us}={st\over ur}={su\over us}=1$$

Since $st=ur$ we have ${s\over u}={r\over t}$ hence parallel.

Answer (score 0):

From $$\frac{XP}{PY} = \frac{\triangle AXP}{\triangle AYP} = \frac{\frac{1}{2} AX \cdot AP \cdot \sin \angle XAP}{\frac{1}{2} AY \cdot AP \cdot \sin \angle YAP} = \frac{AX \cdot \sin \angle XAP}{AY \cdot \sin \angle YAP}$$ and $$\frac{BQ}{CQ} = \frac{\triangle ABQ}{\triangle ACQ} = \frac{\frac{1}{2} AB \cdot AQ \cdot \sin \angle BAQ}{\frac{1}{2} AC \cdot AQ \cdot \sin \angle CAQ} = \frac{AB \cdot \sin \angle XAP}{AC \cdot \sin \angle YAP}$$

We have $$\frac{XP}{YP}=\frac{BQ}{CQ} \iff \frac{AX}{AY}=\frac{AB}{AC} \iff XY \parallel BC \iff \frac{AX}{XB} = \frac{AY}{YC}$$

By Ceva's Theorem, we have $$\frac{XP}{PY}=\frac{BQ}{CQ}=\frac{AX}{XB} \cdot \frac{BQ}{CQ} \cdot \frac{CY}{AY}=1$$